# How to Bridge ERC-20 Tokens to a Similar Contract on Solana Using Wormhole or Equivalent Platform?

Tags: spl-token-program

I am currently working on a blockchain project where I’ve encountered a challenge that I hope to get some insights on.

**Background**:

I have an existing ERC-20 token contract on Ethereum, which includes buy and sell taxes.

I’ve created a similar contract on the Solana blockchain, aiming to mirror the structure and functionality of the ERC-20 token.

**Challenge**:

My primary goal is to bridge these two tokens across the Ethereum and Solana blockchains. I am considering using Wormhole or a similar bridging platform for this purpose.

**Specific Questions**:

1. What are the key considerations or steps I should be aware of when bridging ERC-20 tokens to a Solana-based contract using Wormhole or a similar platform?
2. Are there any specific technical challenges or limitations in connecting these two contracts across different blockchains?
3. Can someone provide insights or examples of similar implementations, or point me toward relevant resources or documentation that might help?
   I appreciate any guidance or advice the community can offer on this matter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!